# Showing output of piped command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, piping

I am automating Office365 mailboxes. I am running the following command in PowerShell

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {Name -like "T1-*"} | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
select Displayname, LastLogonTime | Export-Csv "lastlogon-all.csv"
```

The command works, after initiating a session. The Get-Mailbox results also have a PrimarySmtpAddress field. I would like to include that in the ouput, but because of piping, it is lost.

How do I get that field in my output?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {Name -like "T1-*"} |
  foreach {
    $address = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress;
    $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics |
    select Displayname, LastLogonTime, @{ Name = "PrimarySmtpAddress"; Expression = { $address } }
  } |
  Export-Csv "lastlogon-all.csv"
```

There might also be possible to access the mailbox-object trough the statistics-object, but the documentation does not mention which objects are returned by the respective commands.

Comment: Result : "Pipeline not run because a pipeline is already running. Pipelines cannot be run concurrently."
Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I solved it. The get-mailbox results need to be stored in a variable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Markus Jarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22364/markus-jarderot) I got the solution:

```
$boxes = Get-Mailbox -Filter {Name -like "T1-*"} 
$boxes |  foreach {
    $address = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress; 
    $_  | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
        select Displayname, LastLogonTime, @{ Name = "PrimarySmtpAddress"; Expression = { $address } }
  } | 
  Export-Csv "lastlogon-all.csv"
```

Possibly the address doesn't have to be formatted, so you could suffice with select $address